# Form validation class not recognised Laravel 5.1

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to validate an email field on a Post request in Laravel 5.1.

On my Controller i have 'use App\Http\Requests;' but I get an error message 'Class App\Http\Controllers\StorePotentialUserRequest does not exist'. (For some reason it's looking for the class in the controller).

The class IS found when i have 'use App\Http\Requests\StorePotentialUserRequest;'. But I feel that this shouldn't be the case..

I also can't 'use App\Http\Requests\Request' because there is a conflict with 'use Illuminate\Http\Request'.

My code in the controller is as follows:

```
 public function create(StorePotentialUserRequest $request)
    {
        ...
```

EDIT: works if you namespace the code class as follows:

```
public function create(\App\Http\Requests\StorePotentialUserRequest $request)
    {
       ...
```

But this is not mentioned on the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are in the same namespace, you **do** have to specify where in the namespace are the classes you are using.

Either with **use** or with the full path every time you refer it.